# Find the minimum difference of all possible pairs

Tags: c++, arrays

Given 3 numeric sorted arrays:

```
int[] a;
int[] b;
int[] c;
```

It is necessary to find three numbers whose difference is minimal:
`(a_i- b_j)^2 + (b_j - c_k)^2 + (a_i - c_k)^2` -> min

For examle:

```
int[] a = {7, 10, 12};
int[] b = {3, 4, 6, 9};
int[] c = {1, 2, 5, 8};
```

Result should be 7 6 8 (or 7 6 5) because `(7 - 6)^2 + (6 - 5)^2 + (7 - 5)^2 = 6 = min`

What is the best approach to this problem?

I`ve tried to use 3 variables and increment them depending on the minimum term, but unsuccessfully.
Here is my algorithm written in C++:

```
void printThreeClosest(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {
    int64_t diff = (a[0] - b[0]) * (a[0] - b[0]) +
                   (b[0] - c[0]) * (b[0] - c[0]) +
                   (a[0] - c[0]) * (a[0] - c[0]);

    int i_res = 0, j_res = 0, k_res = 0, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < a.size() && j < b.size() && k < c.size()) {
        int first_term = (a[i] - b[j]) * (a[i] - b[j]);
        int second_term = (b[j] - c[k]) * (b[j] - c[k]);
        int third_term = (a[i] - c[k]) * (a[i] - c[k]);

        int min_term = std::min(a[i], std::min(b[j], c[k]));

        int64_t current_diff = first_term + second_term + third_term;

        if (current_diff < diff) {
            diff = current_diff;
            i_res = i, j_res = j, k_res = k;
        }

        if (diff == 0) {
            break;
        }

        if (first_term == min_term) {
            ++k;
        } else if (second_term == min_term) {
            ++i;
        } else {
            ++j;
        }
    }

    std::cout << a[i_res] << " " << b[j_res] << " " << c[k_res] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: In your example, the arrays aren't sorted.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and what *specific* issues you had with it.

Comment: Okay, in the question it says: `(7 - 6)^2 + (6 - 5)^2 + (7 - 5)^2 = 6`. Actually, it is not 6. It is 3. `1 ^2+ 1^2 + 1^2 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3`.
Remember that sum of squares may be minimum when the sum of `absolute difference` is minimum. So, it may be possible that one only needs to find absolute difference of 7, 6, 8. And, please specific which language as well.

Comment: `int min_term = std::min(a[i], std::min(b[j], c[j]));` <--- the last term, does it need to be `c[k]`?

Comment: Consider `a: [1, 19, 20]; b: [15, 16]; c: [17, 18];` The `min_term` will always be `1` (ie, `first_term`). So, the result will be `1, 15, 18` - but it needs to be `19, 16, 18`. Seems that the solution will need to be `O(n^3)`.

Comment: [10, 9, 8], [7, 9, 8] these 2 are also acceptable answer right?
Very straightforward solution would be run 3 nested loops(N^3) , generate all combination of 3 numbers from 3 lists, store minimum output by solving the equations for each of the combination.

Comment: @jsN00b: it doesn't *need* to be `19,16,18`; it could also be `19,16,17`.  And you have no evidence that it *needs* to be O(n^3).

Comment: True `19, 16, 17` is correct. Cheers for pointing that out. It does "seems that" it is O(n^3). Will be happy to learn a better approach - rather than the brute-force one (iterating to each possible combination).

Comment: Your `min_term` isn't the minimum term; it is the minimum of the 3 array elements, and thus you have to reason to expect it to ever be equal to `first_term`, `second_term` or `third_term`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the straight-forward, but `O(n^3)` solution may be this:

```
void printThreeClosest(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {
    int minVal = -1;
    int resa, int resb, int resc;

    for(int i=0; i<a.length && minVal != 0; i++) {
        int x = a[i];
        for(int j=0; j<b.length && minVal != 0; j++) {
            int y = b[j];
            for(int k=0; k<c.length && minVal != 0; k++) {
                int z = c[k];
                int sumOfSqr = ( ((x-y)*(x-y)) + ((y-z)*(y-z)) + ((z-x)*(z-x)) );
                if (minVal < 0) {
                    minVal = sumOfSqr;
                    resa=x; resb=y; resc=z;
                } else if (sumOfSqr < minVal) {
                    minVal = sumOfSqr;
                    resa=x; resb=y; resc=z;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    std::cout << resa << ' ' << resb << ' ' << resc << std::endl;
}
```

This solution implemented in Javascript for quick testing is below:

```js
const a = [7, 10, 12];
const b = [3, 4, 6, 9];
const c = [1, 2, 5, 8];

let minVal = -1;
let result = [];

const sumOfSquares = (x, y, z) => ( ((x-y)*(x-y)) + ((y-z)*(y-z)) + ((x-z)*(x-z)) );

for (let i=0; i < a.length && minVal !== 0; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j < b.length && minVal !== 0; j++) {
    for (let k=0; k < c.length && minVal !== 0; k++) {
        const tempSum = sumOfSquares(a[i], b[j], c[k]);
        if (minVal < 0) {
        minVal = tempSum;
        result = [a[i], b[j], c[k]];
      } else if (tempSum < minVal) {
        minVal = tempSum;
        result = [a[i], b[j], c[k]];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log('result: ', result);
```